# Messages Lost after Spring Integration Splitter. Data not reaching Aggregator randomly

Tags: spring-integration, splitter, aggregator

I am trying to process the output of a SQL query in parallel. below given is my code. I have sysout in Aggregator. But I randomly see the sysout in Aggregator is not getting printed. Also, the release method in aggregator is also not printing sysouts. I guess, I am losing the messages some where. Can any one shed some light?

```
    <int:bridge input-channel="inputChannel" output-channel="dbRequestChannel" />

        <jdbc:outbound-gateway request-channel="dbRequestChannel"
            max-rows-per-poll="0" data-source="dataSource" reply-channel="headerEnricher"
            query="select empname, empno, empdob from employee where empno = 1234" />

        <int:header-enricher input-channel="headerEnricher"
            output-channel="splitterChannel">
            <int:header name="payloadSize" value="3"></int:header>
        </int:header-enricher>

        <int:chain input-channel="splitterChannel" output-channel="splitterOutputChannel">
            <int:splitter />
        </int:chain>


        <int:channel id="splitterOutputChannel">
            <int:dispatcher task-executor="sampleTaskExecutor" />
        </int:channel>

        <bean id="sampleTaskExecutor"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
            <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
            <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
        </bean>

        <int:service-activator input-channel="splitterOutputChannel"
            ref="springIntegrationtest" method="testMethod" output-channel="aggregatePayload">
        </int:service-activator>

        <int:aggregator input-channel="aggregatePayload"
            release-strategy-method="release" output-channel="nullChannel"
            send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" ref="springIntegrationtest"
            method="aggregateData" />

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-integration.xml" })
public class SpringIntegrationTest {


    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel inputChannel;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");



    @Test
    public void testQueue() {
        Message<String> quoteMessage = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload("testPayload").build();
        inputChannel.send(quoteMessage);
    }


    public Map<String, String> testMethod(Message<?> m) {

        System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
        return (Map<String, String>) m.getPayload();
    }

    public boolean release(ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> payload) {
        boolean release = false;
        int size = payload.size();
        if (size == 3) {
            release = true;
        }
        System.out.println(release);
        return release;
    }

    public Message<String> aggregateData(ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> payload) {

        System.out.println("In aggregateData " + payload);
        Message<String> quoteMessage = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload("testPayload").build();
        return quoteMessage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think your problem is with the combination of states and options.

You have this:

```
int size = payload.size();
if (size == 3) {
    release = true;
}
```

so, your aggregator is going to release the group just after a `3` items arrived, meanwhile you may have much more items after splitting.

The `release` signals aggregator to finish the group and exit. By default it has an option like `expireGroupsUponCompletion = false`, which means *retain* group in the store but with the `completed` state.

If your goal just to emit from aggregator tuples by 3, you should consider to switch the `expireGroupsUponCompletion` to `true`. See aggregator [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator) for more information.

Comment: The output of the query always returns only 3 results. That is why for the sake of testing, i added this condition.

Comment: Ok. Provide then, please, debug logs for org.springframework.integration